# site crashed after changing css settings

Tags: magento2, admin, css

On my Mac localhost, in admin - store - configurations, I changed my css compilation to client side configuration in advanced and now everything is fried and I can't get back. This is the result:
FileError: 'http://127.0.0.1/Magento/pub/static/version1489371700/_cache/merged/source/_responsive.less' wasn't found (404)
in db6b6fc668e0d14d1ee9a8f367faf3db.css on line 30, column 1:

29
@import 'source/components/_rules-temp.less';

30
@import 'source/_responsive.less';

31
/* The above import directives are aggregated from content. */

Comment: In your Magento root directory run this `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`, also run on developer mode.

Answer (score 0):

In your Magento root directory set your site in developer mode and run this command:

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`